# Does ESPN Cricinfo have an API?

Tags: web-services, api, espn

Has [espncricinfo.com](http://espncricinfo.com) exposed an API?  I'm interested in live scores, news, and maybe photos.

Up until now I have only known of the rss feed..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I do not believe an API exists - unfortunately.

What a number of users have done - and what is suggested by cricinfo themselves - is use Yahoo Pipes to merge a number of different feeds. You can then get the resultant pipe in JSON and other formats.

It's probably best demonstrated by example by looking at a 'Latest cricket scores' pipe here: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=tMcVGcqn3BGvsT__2R2EvQ

Of course, it would be nice to be able to search the statistics and a REST service which returns the bare data for a [statsguru](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/stats/index.html) search, but the only suggestion I have at present is to build statsguru queries manually with `wrappertype=print` appended and then use xpath to filter out the data you require.

An example statsguru query:

http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/13418.html?class=1;template=results;type=allround;wrappertype=print

Comment: another problem is that how to get international scores only?

Comment: pipe mentioned in your answer only gives links to cricinfo links - question is meant for apis for cricket scores, news?

Comment: CricInfo is being migrated to the ESPN APIs and hopefully will be complete this year.

Comment: and now Yahoo pipes don't work ! any alternative ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Yahoo! Query Language (YQL) for fetching latest cricket data. It returns the result both in JSON and XML format. You can find it here : http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?env=store://0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0&_uiFocus=cricket

Comment: Good link, but can you post the core code from it?

Answer (score 4):

ESPN Developer Center Launches, Opens Sports APIs to App Builders:
The Headlines API is free for non-commercial use in apps performing up to 2,500 API calls per day. As outside apps that use ESPN APIs increase in user base, developers enter individual partnership agreements with the company. If you want to use ESPN's new APIs, visit the Developer Center ( http://developer.espn.com/ ) and request a developer key.

Comment: Unfortunately, these apis don't cover cricket yet.

Comment: As of Monday, December 8, 2014, this has been shutdown.