# Get the API for making the application

Tags: android, api

Is there any API for

> ESPN
>
> WSJ
>
> GridLoyalty

and

> BubbleMotion

I want to data in JSON format. Please give me link of the api.

Thanx in Advance...!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127616/espn-cricinfo-api I think this may help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an API exists for ESPN still.

WSJ => http://rodowen.com/images/WSJFoundationAPIGuide.pdf

For GridLoyalty and BubbleMotion also I don't think an API exists.

Comment: I have already this pdf file. But I have not any file which is given in the pdf. So how I can get the link for download that files.

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/ go to this page and search for "Wall Street Journal"

Comment: can you send me the complete link, Plz...

Answer (score 0):

Log onto the ESPN website to find details about their API's. All you need to do is register for an API key and you are good to go

Comment: The question isn't a great one, but a link to the API page would be very helpful in an answer.